# Compute interval score for interval predictions in R

Tags: r, prediction, quantile-regression

At the thread of stackexchange: "forecast-accuracy-metric-that-involves-prediction-intervals" for more details see the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194660/forecast-accuracy-metric-that-involves-prediction-intervals) where a quality measure for prediction interval is shown.

I would like to compute quality meassure in R:

```
library(quantreg)

## Split data 
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(iris))
set.seed(123)

train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size = smp_size)
train <- iris[train_ind, ]
test <- iris[-train_ind, ]

# Training model for prediction intervals, lw(lower) and up(upper) intervals
model_lw <- rq(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data= train, tau = 0.1)
model_up <- rq(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data= train, tau = 0.9)

# Interval Predictions, lw(lower) and up(upper) intervals
pred_lw <- predict(model_lw, test)
pred_up <- predict(model_up, test)
```

By using the products:

```
pred_lw,pred_up & test$Sepal.Length
```

#### Goal

- An interval quality meassure could be computed. I would like to find an implementation library for interval perdiction evaluation.
- An alternative solution could be computing the "coverage and length of the prediction intervals" or any other evaluation metric.

Any help on this implementation?

Comment: have you had a look a the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/vignettes/rq.pdf) of quantreg? They look pretty complete to me on the analysis... A bit too much hard-coding imho, but it gets the work done. I think that the right error evaluation depends on your business target and this goes beyond StackOverflow goals. PS: I suggest you to use `tau = c(0.1,0.9)` instead of two separated line of code.

Comment: I didnt find anything useful at the documentation, any adivce for evaluate in some way the Intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For evaluation prediction intervals for quantle regression, two implementation solutions are found, with any other metrics included `scoringutils` and `greybox`.

## Solution

```
library(scoringutils)
# Scoring Rule to score quantile predictions, (Gneiting & Raftery, 2007)
mean(interval_score(true_values = test$Sepal.Length, 
               lower = pred_lw, 
               upper = pred_up, 
               interval_range = 80))

library(greybox)
# Mean Interval Score (Gneiting & Raftery, 2007),
MIS(actual = test$Sepal.Length, 
    lower = pred_lw, 
    upper = pred_up, 
    level = 0.80)

# interval range or level -> 0.9 - 0.1 = 0.8 (80)
```

In the second package a symetric and relative score measure are avaliable, further study should be done in order to undertand the bias and aplications of this metrics with some other statistics.

hope this helps to the community